# Unable to load internal .js files on webserver

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am trying to load the highstocks files on my webserver, and when i use

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

It works completely fine, but on my server I try to load

```
<script src="highstocks/code/js/highstock.js"></script>
```

And it dosent work, when I inspect the site (which you can look at: weather.wesleyweisenberger.com) the link points to the correct file, yet it does not load highcharts. 
I have used `chown -R` and `chmod -R 755` on the highstocks folder, yet I cannot load the file into the website. I have had similar issues with trying to load materialize or jQuery.
Help would be Appreaciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of imports matter in your case. You need to add the highstock import line before the export js lines, like below

```
<!-- Import highcharts -->
    <script src="highstocks/code/js/highstock.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

Because exporting.js requires highstock.js, and the order is incorrect only when you add from local like below,

```
<!-- Import highcharts -->
    <!-- <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>

    <script src="highstocks/code/js/highstock.js"></script> <!-- wrong order -->
```

Comment: I don't actually require the exporting.js or the export-data.js anymore, but even with them removed I cannot import highstock.js

Comment: Now there is an error in line 102 : color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
You need to find some other way to provide color, because Highcharts.getOptions() does not have color defined. Fix it and there should be progress

Comment: Got it! I ended up loading highstocks/highstock.js rather than highstocks/js/highstock.js because it gave me a black screen, do you know why this is?

Comment: You included styled version of Highcharts (`js/something.js`). From docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css : `In these files, most presentational code is removed, so without styling it will draw an ugly black-and-white chart if anything.`